# Is it possible to do a shuffle in this manner with a boolean instead of a list?

Tags: java, eclipse, computer-science

Here my code (In Java on Eclipse) displays 3 random cards from the a file. I am trying to get a shuffle button to work and randomly shuffle in 3 new cards. I used "Collections.shuffle(cards);" and passed it my boolean array but it says I can't because it wants a List<> list. Is it possible to get the shuffle to work with my boolean or would I have to use a List?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DisplayCards extends Application {
    
    HBox imageViews;

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        boolean[] cards = new boolean[52];
        int count = 0;
        while(count <3) {
            int card = (int)(Math.random() * 52);
            
            if(!cards[card]) {
                cards[card] = true;
                pane.add(new ImageView(new Image("card/" + (card) + ".png")), count, 0);
                count++;
            }
        }
        imageViews = new HBox();
        imageViews.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        shuffle();
    
        
        Button btnShuffle = new Button("Shuffle");
        btnShuffle.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                shuffle();
                
            }
        });
        
        BorderPane Bpane = new BorderPane();
        Bpane.setCenter(imageViews);
        Bpane.setBottom(btnShuffle);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Display 4 Cards");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
    }

    private void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(cards);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    

}
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as pictures, instead post it as text directly inside the question, in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By the way, you can convert your array to a `List` and shuffle that.

Comment: I just changed it from pictures to text

Comment: I would not use boolean array to represent cards.  Can you tell which card are in this array?  [true,true] and [true, true]?

Comment: @ChengThao it randomly selects three cards out of 51 in a file using the cards name in the file with the file extension of ".png". The names are "card1.png", "card2.png", "card3.png", etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the Fisher–Yates shuffle for an array.

```java
private void shuffle(){
    for(int i = cards.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        int j = java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(i + 1);
        boolean temp = cards[i];
        cards[i] = cards[j];
        cards[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible could you explain this I haven't seen this type of shuffle yet.

Comment: @lilgudo See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle